# MTU sweep for ipv6 ping6?

Tags: ping, ipv6

The answer to [Is there an equivalent utility to Linux's tracepath for OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125068/is-there-an-equivalent-utility-to-linuxs-tracepath-for-os-x) suggests to use

```
ping -g 1444 -G 1508 -c 2 -h 1 -D example.com
```

How do I modify this for ipv6? Tried

```
ping6 -g 1444 -G 1508 -c 2 -h 1 -D 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

but this gives a `ping6: getaddrinfo for the gateway 1444: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` error.

EDIT: If you wish to determine the MTU of a path then don't forget `-m` as described here https://njetwork.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/ping6-and-fragments/ and use `netstat -narWl -f inet6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first place to look for more info on commands is its manual page (`man ping6`):

```
 -G sweepmaxsize[,sweepminsize[,sweepincrsize]]
         sweepmaxsize specifies the maximum size of the payload when sending
         sweeping pings and is required for sweeps.  sweepminsize specifies
         the size of the payload to start with when sending sweeping pings
         -- the default value is 0.  sweepincrsize specifies the number of
         bytes to increment the size of the payload after each sweep when
         sending sweeping pings -- the default value is 1.  This option is
         an Apple addition.
```

So, running something like

```
ping6 -G 1508,1444 -c 2 -h 1 -D 2606:4700:4700::1111
```

should work.

PS: When I tested this, I also had to remove `-D`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your methodology